# Can I use a D bamboo flute to play a C key

Tags: key, instruments, flute

I actually want to buy a D bamboos flute but I would like to know whether I can use it to play other keys as well

Comment: IMO, if you just want to _have fun_, it's best to stick to whatever things a flute like that naturally wants to do, and not try to force it to do any specific key or song or anything. Unless you're an actual professional flutist and/or want to spend years mastering that particular instrument.

Comment: Not conversant with the instrument, so a comment. It's probably *diatonic* - having ony the notes from the stated key. C has 2 different notes from D - no F#, C#, F,C instead.  Both important notes in key C. So little chance, really. With a range of maybe an octave, playing even in D may be impossible for some tunes - moving them to key A would exacerbate the problem, notwithstanding lack of G#. Having said that, it may be a chromatic instrument, in which case, all keys are available, but range is still a problem.

Comment: @Tim looking at this https://www.sideblown.com/Finger.html it seems that everything is possible in theory ... but, quote: "_Every flute is unique because of the natural bore of the bamboo. One fingering may work fine for one flute and not the other, especially in the higher notes._"

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - many thanks for that. As I suspected, each flute is in a basic key - rather like trumpet in Bb, in C, in D. Xaphoons work the same. And using a 'half-hole' technique, the player can raise/lower any diatonic note to produce chromatics. With enough skill !

Answer (score 5):

You’ve not really provided enough information, so I’m going to assume that it’s a keyless flute and also that it’s been made as a musical instrument rather than a toy or a tourist knick-knack.

If it’s a D flute with six finger holes and D being the note sounding with all holes closed, you can easily play in D, G, and (with a cross fingering) A. Playing in C will require you to cross-finger the f note - xxxx0x might produce a passable f, or maybe xxx0xx or xxxxv0 [where x is a closed hole, 0 is an open hole, v is a half-closed hole, your mouth is at the left hand side].

So it’s doable, but you’re going to need to practice practice practice, and the f note might be weak so try to avoid tunes that emphasise the f if possible.

Comment: In addition to the sharps and flats, isn't range an issue as well?

Comment: Almost no bamboo flutes will produce the minor third (F on a D flute) with cross fingering. Half-holing is the only option. Generally the only non-diatonic note available with cross-fingerings is the the minor seventh (C on a D flute), and the exact fingerings differ from flute to flute and octave to octave. .

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Range is an issue, but sometimes it can be an advantage to play a piece on a flute in a differenet key. A piece in C might lie much better on a G flute.

Answer (score 1):

For a versatile approach I would recommend a recorder instead. 
The ones out of plastic are comparatively cheap even from well known brands.

This assumes your choice was due to price; if you like the sound, you have to stick with appropriate pieces or become expert in transposition, either in real-time while playing or with notation software.